# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back while decompressing

Tags: compression

util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back this exception when i am decompressing my data....it occurs in this line

```
zipInput = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipInput);
bis.read(buffer);//here exception occurs
```

please help.

Comment: Then the compressed data has been corrupted.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. The error is thrown when the data is parsed incorrectly.

Comment: Then that is _how_ the compressed data was corrupted.

Answer (score 7):

This archieve really has been corrupted. You can form input stream from bytes:

```cs
InputStream bStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

or from file:

```cs
InputStream bStream = new FileInputStream(fis);

ByteArrayOutputStream bOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try{
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bStream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    int len;
```

at some iteration cycle will corrupt

```cs
    while((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){
        bOutStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    bOutStream.close();
    gis.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    bOutStream.close();
    //print unarchieved bytes
    System.out.println(new String(bOutStream.toByteArray()));
}
```

That's why it helps find the place of corruption.
All bytes before this place will be shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

When i have this problem last time - i used apache poi to edit word files and i had to resave files created in Microsoft Office using libre Office as word 2007. Then this error gone.