# java.io.IOException: invalid distance too far back in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I get this strange error in some of my mapreduce jobs

```
java.io.IOException: invalid distance too far back
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:71)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:248)
    at com.contextin.io.VersionedWritable.readFields(VersionedWritable.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.deserializeValue(SequenceFile.java:2180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getCurrentValue(SequenceFile.java:2164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.getCurrentValue(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.next(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:78)
    at com.contextin.model.workflow.AggregateFilesMR$CustomKeyValueLineRecordReader.next(AggregateFilesMR.java:632)
    at com.contextin.model.workflow.AggregateFilesMR$CustomKeyValueLineRecordReader.next(AggregateFilesMR.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileRecordReader.next(CombineFileRecordReader.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Some facts (may or may not be relevant):

- The job uses CustomCombineFileInputFormat - that is, each mapper may handle more then one file
- The error does reoccur quite often, but not always (so it doesn't appear to be purely a bug or software error)
- Some datasets cause this error more often then others (so it appears to be at least related to the data)
- But for the same data set the job may sometime succeed and sometimes fail - so it's NOT strictly a data problem.
- Some of the jobs that run on the machine (not specifically the failing job) have high memory requirements, which cause some tasks to fail because of memory problems. although this specific error doesn't appear to be memory related.

Comment: "so it's strictly a data problem." you meant it's NOT strictly right ?

Comment: According to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151669/java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-distance-too-far-back-while-decompressing the compressed files may be corrupted

Comment: Seen it - but this isn't consistent with the fact that for the same data set the job sometimes does complete successfully.

Comment: This feels a lot like a race condition, we have a few questions similar to this one on SO but with different stack traces :) A interesting one for sure Are you using Writeables for some other serialization format ?

Comment: What do you mean by: "Are you using Writeables for some other serialization format"
We use custom writables if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From further testing, it appears to be a data problem.
Reading some of the files individually (not mapreduce) caused the problem consistently.

I don't have a good explanation why the number of task failures change between runs