# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I have the following error:

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\Mc.android\build-cache\127d5fc12b111a39bc3540138a1d9115714c67ca\output\jars\classes.jar' to 'D:\Android Projects\gcrisk\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\classes_ffaaeeac46b404db5b09fe58052cbbfe4918f022'

I tried to "invalidate cache/restart" but not run and another solutions, but nothing!

i need a help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back while decompressing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151669/java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-distance-too-far-back-while-decompressing)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate, @code-apprentice, this refers to an Android Studio 3.0.1 error. That I keep getting too when I make changes and press "Apply Changes". Almost never works. Right?